# Working with jenkins prometheus plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, monitoring, metrics, prometheus

I have Jenkins in `https://jenkins.example.com`.
Plugin working witn 2 env. variables:

`PROMETHEUS_ENDPOINT Configures rest endpoint. Defaults to "prometheus"
PROMETHEUS_NAMESPACE Configure prometheus metric namespace. Defaults to "default"`

I need the metrics to be sent to `https://jenkins.example.com/metrics`

What `PROMETHEUS_ENDPOINT` and `PROMETHEUS_NAMESPACE` values?

[Plugin documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Prometheus+Plugin)

Comment: I read the documentation, but when I substitute the values of the environment variables, I get an error 404 on these endpoints...
I am junior, and my understanding of this is minimal. Can you describe for me how it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Shortly:** You actually don't need to edit this values. if you wish so you can configure them on:

> Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Promethues (section)

In short `PROMETHEUS_ENDPOINT` using the GET Http request in order to get the index page of the jenkins metrics - `https://<your-jenkins-path>/prometheus`

**Useful / Golden Tips for using jenkins prometheus plugin:**

1. set parameter `Enable authentication for prometheus end-point` to `true` and you'll be able to **get information about internal processes and jobs** running on your jenkins endpoint.
2. create User account on jenkins dedicated to prometheus monitoring, create a token for authentication.
3. set screen privileges permissions for viewing jenkins metrics for this user:

**For Enabling Metrics permission:**

> Managing jenkins -> Manage and assign roles -> Manage Roles -> Metrics
>   (set view and health-check to true).

**For Assign this permission to specific user:** (your prometheus user) -

> Managing jenkins -> Manage and assign roles -> Assign Roles -> find
>   your user and add screen permission.

4. Configure this credentials on prometheus.yml in your prometheus stack. I'm attaching example for this, **this pattern works for me**:

> ```
> - job_name: 'jenkins'
> metrics_path: /prometheus
> scheme: http
> tls_config:
>   insecure_skip_verify: true
> static_configs:
>   - targets: ['company.jenkins.com:8080']
> basic_auth:
>   username: 'JohnDoe@gmail.com'
>   password: 'abc123'
> ```

5. In order to test this is actual works  use **curl** for perform http request the plugin api and integration for jenkins. `curl -u user:token jenkinsURL:port/prometheus/`

for example:

```
curl -u JohnDoe@gmail.com:abc123 company.jenkins.com:8080/prometheus/
```

6. For **testing your integration with prometheus**, go to your `http://yourPrometheusURL.com:9090/targets` and make sure your endpoint is up. you should get the metrics and start using it. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

`PROMETHEUS_ENDPOINT` - Configures the path. Defaults to `prometheus` thus your metrics will be accessible at the URI `/prometheus/`.

What you want is to configure `PROMETHEUS_ENDPOINT` to `metrics`. You will still have to add to `prometheux.xml` the variable `metrics_path` and set it to `/metrics/`

`PROMETHEUS_NAMESPACE` - puts a prefix to each metric.

Answer (score 0):

http://jenkins.example.com/metrics 
change it
 http://jenkins.example.com/prometheus

by using prometheus.yml

change prometheus.yml file

> job_name: Jenkins 
>     scrape_interval: 5s 
>       metrics_path: '/prometheus'
>        scheme: http.
>           tls_config:
>        insecure_skip_verify: true
>       static_configs:
>         - targets: ['jenkins.example.com:8080']

Answer (score 0):

For me it works belowin prometheus.xml file

- job_name: 'jenkins'

  metrics_path: '/jenkins/prometheus'

  scheme: http

  static_configs:

  - targets: ['domainname:port']

  basic_auth:

  username: 'xxxxxx'

  password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'