# Prometheus target returned http status 404 not found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, prometheus

I want to integrate Jenkins with Prometheus and installed the Prometheus plugin on Jenkins and setting the below configuration in Prometheus. The target on the Prometheus is showing "server returned HTTP status 404 Not Found"

The actual URL "https://jenkins_host/prometheus" works fine without any issues.

```
- job_name: 'jenkins'
        metrics_path: /prometheus
        scheme: https
        static_configs: 
          - targets: ['jenkins_host']
        tls_config:
          insecure_skip_verify: true
```

Comment: Not sure, but you can try some of the steps in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57804852/14715054

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have this error working by having the target a GCP load balancer, consider that Prometheus might be hitting the default route, because it's not passing the "Host" header for routing.

Solve by either having Prometheus [pass a Host header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69149931/7348119) or [implementing a default backend](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#default_backend) for your GCP LB